# Can't install Blender in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, ppa, update-manager

```
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-shackleton/droidpad/ubuntu bionic Release                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-shackleton/droidpad-daily/ubuntu bionic Release                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [89.1 kB]
```

Answer (score 3):

*ppa:w-shackleton/droidpad* and *ppa:w-shackleton/droidpad-daily* do not support any Ubuntu release later than 14.04, so they should be removed from the software sources in Ubuntu 18.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:w-shackleton/droidpad ppa:w-shackleton/droidpad-daily  
sudo apt update
```

To install Blender in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu 18.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install blender # recommended
```

To install the latest stable version of Blender in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu 18.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install blender --classic
```